# Version mismatch while loading sklearn.ensemble RandomForestModel ( built on VM ), on docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, scikit-learn

I have built a random forest model on VM. It has python 3.5.3, sklearn 0.0 and scikit-learn 0.22.2.post1. I am building a docker with python 3.6 Docker and installing the exact versions and packages as present on VM (Note: did pip freeze to requirement.txt and using that to install requirements on docker).

The error found when docker logs are checked after build is as follows:

```
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble._forest'**.
```

I also tried building the same module with python 3.7 but i am not able to install python 3.5 or 3.7 on docker. The models are being stored as joblib files.

Comment: PS : The script works fine on VM with the aforementioned versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scikit-learn==0.20.4 package, it worked for me with python-3.7. The latest version 0.23.1 gives you 'sklearn.ensemble._forest' error.